# Is Core data the same as cookies?

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and I'm building on a simple app that relies on login/sign up functions for each user. When I wanted to learn about databases in Swift, I came across Core Data and from what I understood it's like cookies/cache that stores data in the user's phone. If that's so, what's the best way to connect the app to a regular database like SQL?

Comment: check this out :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51219869/best-method-to-store-data-for-an-ios-app

Comment: Question seems clear enough to me... why was this closed?

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is an ORM (object-relational mapping) system. Overly simplyfied you build your data model entities and and relationships between them and Core Data cares about the rest. Under the hood it uses an SQLite database by default, but it also can handle other types of storage (e.g. binary or XML).

To answer your question, for Login/Signup purposes you should look into storing user data such as auth tokens etc. in the Keychain.